# AWS Cloudformation template EC2 Role/Policy circular dependency

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am writing a Cloudformation template with a single EC2 instance and an EBS volume. I attach the volume later on at some point when the machine is created using Powershell script. It works when I put wildcard '*' in policy statement resource however I want to limit the access to one instance and one ebs volume. With EBS volume it's easy I can just refer it in the template and it is created before the role but with instance the problem is that instance requires the role to be created first but also to be able to create the instance we need to create the role first. What's a good way of resolving this kind of circular dependency?

Here is my template:

```
Resources:
  InstanceRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      RoleName: InstanceRole
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ec2.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: AttachVolume
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 'ec2:AttachVolume'
                Resource:
                  - !Join 
                    - ''
                    - - 'arn:aws:ec2:'
                      - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
                      - ':'
                      - !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
                      - ':instance/*'
                  - !Join 
                    - ''
                    - - 'arn:aws:ec2:'
                      - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
                      - ':'
                      - !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
                      - ':volume/'
                      - !Ref DataVolume             
  InstanceProfile:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile'
    Properties:
      Roles:
        - !Ref InstanceRole
      InstanceProfileName: InstanceProfile
  Instance:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      ImageId: !Ref AMI
      InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
      IamInstanceProfile: !Ref InstanceProfile
      KeyName: ec2key
      BlockDeviceMappings:
        - DeviceName: /dev/sda1
          Ebs:
            VolumeType: gp2
            DeleteOnTermination: 'true'
            VolumeSize: '30'
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: MyInstance
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetId
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref SGId
      UserData: !Base64 
        'Fn::Join':
          - ''
          - - |
              <script>
            - 'cfn-init.exe -v -c config -s '
            - !Ref 'AWS::StackId'
            - ' -r Instance'
            - ' --region '
            - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
            - |+

            - |
              </script>
  DataVolume:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::Volume"
    Properties:  
      AvailabilityZone: !GetAtt 
        - Instance
        - AvailabilityZone
      Size: "100"
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: InstanceExtraVolume
```

Answer (score 2):

In your particular example, you have the following dependency chain: `InstanceRole -> DataVolume -> Instance -> InstanceProfile -> InstanceRole`

In general, when your **Role** depends on your **Resources** and your **Resources** depend on your **Role**, this is where the [AWS::IAM::Policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-policy.html) resource type is useful. This basically decouples the particular policy on the **IAM Role** from being resolved at the same time as the **IAM Policy** itself.

To do this, you would take your **InstanceRole** and split it into an **InstanceRole** and an **InstanceRolePolicy**

```
Resources:
  InstanceRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      RoleName: InstanceRole
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ec2.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: /
  InstanceRolePolicy:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Policy'
    Properties:
      Roles:
        - !Ref InstanceRole
      PolicyName: AttachVolume
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - 'ec2:AttachVolume'
            Resource:
              - !Join 
                - ''
                - - 'arn:aws:ec2:'
                  - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
                  - ':'
                  - !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
                  - ':instance/*'
              - !Join 
                - ''
                - - 'arn:aws:ec2:'
                  - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
                  - ':'
                  - !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
                  - ':volume/'
                  - !Ref DataVolume
```

With that, the **InstanceRolePolicy** depends on the **InstanceRole** and **DataVolume**, but the **InstanceRole** doesn't depend on anything, so the `DataVolume -> Instance -> InstanceProfile -> InstanceRole` chain can resolve.

Comment: Is this a recommended way? AWS has a [note](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-policy.html#cfn-iam-policy-roles) saying that we should also `DependsOn` property to the resource i.e instance in this case which again will introduce circular dependency. What happens if I don't add the `DependsOn` property?

Answer (score 0):

One common solution to circular dependencies is to do this is multiple steps: create the stack with minimal resources, then modify the template and update the stack.

So, v1 of your template creates just the basic dependent resource and in v2, you modify the template to add the depending resource and modify the original dependent resource at the same time. Then do a stack update.

Also, see [more ideas](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/unable-validate-circular-dependency-cloudformation/).

Comment: One of the main advantages of IaC is being able to quickly re-provision a stack. If you have to modify your template every time you start from scratch, it really defeats that purpose. I manage hundreds of stacks and I never had to resort to this.

Comment: Yes, ideally you would not have circular dependencies but for the few cases where it may be unavoidable (and I'm not saying that *this* is one of those cases), one option is create a basic stack then update it. Ugly, yes.